# Should views be created using "Edit the Current View" in the web part menu?

Tags: web-part, list, list-view, view

I've heard (and previous experience supports) that using "Edit the current view" is a bad idea, because the "view" created using this method can be orphaned if the list/library the view is based off of is deleted. The orphaned view can then cause issues during migration. Does anyone else have experience/documentation that supports this? Links online all promote using this method for the obvious end user benefit. However, if teaching end users a different way to achieve their goals can decrease substantial migration headache later, then that seems to be the better path to take. However, I can't find anything to back this up. Am I amiss?

Comment: Just ancedotal, I prefer to create the view, then use it in the web part because chances are if users see the data in the web part, there's a good chance if someone navigates to the list, it's beneficial to have.

Comment: This is my feeling also, but a number of well-respected folk have advised against this approach as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything on the site collection health checklist that would raise any red flags.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219720.aspx

As a quick test, you could create a site collection in 2010 and recreate your scenario.  Then take that content database and upgrade it to 2013.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219474.aspx